Book or curriculum for teaching base-16 numeral system to elementary, middle, or high school children?
In 1862, John W. Nystrom promoted the base-16 (hexadecimal) number system, which he called the "tonal system": Project of a New System of Arithmetic, Weight, Measure and Coins: Proposed to Be Called the Tonal System, With Sixteen to the Base:

Are there math books that teach elementary, middle, or high school children the base-16 (hexadecimal) numeral system?

FWIW, hexadecimal is widely used in computer science. Not for by-hand calculations, of course.

Back in the days of home-brew computing, we all had to know hexadecimal.  65535 = FF.  But nowadays it is not needed.  Do not teach  it to elementary, middle, or high-school students.

@Adam Yes, all the more reason it should be taught to children early on.

@GeraldEdgar Why? Shouldn't they know how computers work?

It seems to me that base-16 doesn't explain how "computers work" but rather how "programmers work". If you want to teach how computers work, you should teach binary base (which doesn't seem like a better idea).

If I had to teach this at this level, I would try this: What are these letters on the calculator? They are used to represent numbers in a different way: number 10 has a special symbol, which is A; B is 11 and so on. This representation is important in computer science, but it's not that easy to do operations using it. However, these calculators allow us to easily transform one representation into another and perform operations using them. Teach them how to use the calculator and ask things like "what is AA+AB in decimal base? Is it 155 or 341?" Of course, this wouldn't take more than one class

As an application (or motivation) you could use color representation: teach them how to convert RGB to hex triplet. Use a color-picker to check the result (as well as to find out what color a given six-digit hexadecimal number represents and vice versa). In this case, more than one class may be needed.

Do a web search for "base 16 blocks" or "hexadecimal blocks." The key word "block" will put you in the world of elementary school teaching, where blocks, flats,  longs, cubes are used to teach place value. You will find hits for base 16 blocks.

Just use your own material. It is nor worth using a book .For young children use the picture of a hand with 8 fingers, you can pint the 3 extra fingers on a paper and place the hands on it to do calculation like in the decimal system.

@GeraldEdgar I believe 0xFF is 255.

@Adam of course.  $65535$ = FFFF
